# Which is more common - mathbb $\mathbb{R}$ or mathbf $\mathbf{R}$?

Tags: notation, soft-question

I've seen people using both, but which is the more commonly accepted symbol to denote the set of real numbers? 
$\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbf{R}$?

Are there any precedents, or any traditional customs as to which is more widely used?

Comment: Definitely $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I could see this depending on culture.

Comment: Amusingly, traditionally $\mathbb{R}$ was just a way of faking regular boldface when writing on a blackboard (hence "blackboard bold"); older books used $\mathbf{R}$. When many books were typewritten, boldface was standard. Blackboard bold became more common as it became easier to produce without having to go through an expensive publisher/galley-proofs to get it.

Comment: Yeah mostly when I see something like $\mathbf{R}$ in math S.E, I mostly assume the person didn't know how to write $\mathbb{R}$. This was the first I heard that older books use $\mathbf{R}$

Comment: A historical note: in the very early days of LaTex (I believe it was only TeX back then) people who did not like bold face letters had to use `$I\!\!R, Z\!\!\!Z, I\!\!\!Q$` because `\mathbb` did not exist.

Comment: @KurtG: By TeX 3.0, it existed in AMS-$\TeX$, as mentioned in _The $\TeX$book... though it specifies that they are not available in plain $\TeX$, but are available in AMS-TeX. (page 164, in a "double dangerous bend" paragraph. "A more extensive set of math fonts would also include script, Fraktur, and "blackgoard bold" styles; plain $\TeX$ doesn't have these, but other formats like AMS-$\TeX$ do.".  My version is copyrighted 1986, though it does say it incorporates corrections made in 1994.

Comment: Could just make a web crawler that counts how many times either appears on this site, and use that empirical number tbh

Comment: @ArturoMagidin . Thanks a lot. Back in those days it was quite a hassle to get TeX installed. Most people that I knew had to use boxes in the basement of the institute and they had only plain TeX.